# I need a uDIG tutorials

Tags: java

Do you know any good tutorials - how to create plug-ins to uDIG application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tutorial in PDF form [here](http://udig.refractions.net/files/tutorials/ToolPluginTutorial.pdf)

(retrieved from a tutorial page [here](http://udig.refractions.net/confluence/display/DEV/2+Plugin+Tutorial) that at the time of writing is down. The above tutorial was referenced from the Google cache)

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial training course available; the first day of which is [available onlinelink text](http://udig.refractions.net/confluence/display/DEV/1+Getting+Started) or in the eclipse help menu after you have completed the SDK Setup instructions.

These materials cover "day one" setup, produce a plugin, and package up your own custom app. the workbench selection tutorial is not uDig specific - it answers the question of "where to start" when working with the Eclipse RCP platform.

I cannot post more hyper links, check the developers guide for the following pages:

1. SDK Quickstart (developers guide, pdf tutorial)
2. Plugin Tutorial (developers guide, pdf tutorial)
3. Custom App (developers guide, pdf tutorial)
4. Workbench Selection (developers guide, pdf tutorial)

If you are an academic the full commercial materials are available; ask your professor to email one of the project steering committee members.

Finally the source code for the tutorials is available in version control; and is actually included in your SDK. You can import these tutorials into your workspace following the instructions here:

- Code Examples (developers guide)
- Training Materials (developers guide)